# The web Dialog on XOJO web application does not close

Tags: xojo

In my web application I have opened a web dialog, which has 2 canvas. On this canvas I have drawn a eyeglass lens. The canvas opens properly and the lens is also drawn properly on it, but after that when i try to close the web dialog, it is not closing.
I think it web dialog hangs after opening and painting on canvas.
Also when I deploy it on XOJO cloud, the application does not open that dialog at all.

Comment: You probably need to show the code used for opening the dialog and closing the dialog for anyone to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using canvas and one property of canvas that is "Diff Engine" was disabled, which i have to enable to speed up the process of drawing.